# For $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, when is $a^3 = b^3$?

Tags: complex-numbers

As the title states. This seems as if it should be really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Obviously, $a = c$ is a solution. I've tried something along the lines of 
$$(a+bi)^3 = (c+di)^3$$
but this hasn't really taken me anywhere. Am I missing something big here?

Apparently,
$$a = \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}\,i}{2}c$$ is also a solution, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to get there myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A polar form might help.

Comment: Hint: solve $0=a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Alt hint: solve $(a/b)^3=1$. P.S. What is $c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $a^3 = b^3$ then $(\frac{a}{b})^3 = 1$. Let $z = \frac{a}{b}$ then $$z^3 = 1 \implies z^3-1=0 \implies (z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0 \implies z = 1,\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Therefore
$$a = b ~~~\mbox{or}~~~a = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}b ~~~\mbox{or}~~~a = \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}b $$

Comment: There is no canonical function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$ that one can denote $\sqrt[3]{\ }$. Please avoid this misleading notation.

Comment: Sorry for this. That's right. Thanks @Did

Answer (score 3):

Polar form was made for this.

Let $a = r_a*e^{i\theta_a}$ and $b= r_b*e^{i\theta_b}$ so $a^3 = b^3$ means $r_a^3 e^{i3\theta_a} = r_b^3 e^{i3\theta_b}$ which means.

$r_a^3 = r_a^3; r_a, r_b \ge 0; r_a, r_b \in \mathbb R$.  So $r_a = r_b$.

And $ e^{i3\theta_a} =  e^{i3\theta_b}$ which means $3\theta_a = 3\theta_b \pm 2k\pi$.

So $\theta_a = \theta_b \pm \frac 23k\pi$

So $a^3 = b^3$ means $a = b*e^{i\frac 23k\pi}$

$e^{i\frac 23\pi} = $ a basic third-root of unity $= \cos (\arctan \frac 23 \pi) + i \sin (\arctan 23 \pi)= \frac {-1 + \sqrt{3}i}2 = \omega$ and $\omega^3 = 1$.

So the three solutions are $b = a; a*\omega; a*\omega^2$ where $\omega^2 = \frac {-1 - \sqrt{3}i}2$.

You can verify this be noting $(\frac {-1 + i\sqrt{3}}2)^3=1$

Comment: Perhaps this is juvenile of me, but I prefer to avoid polar form - an excellent response either way. Thanks!

Comment: I can understand that.  (x,y) -> x + iy in a rectangular grid seems more straight forward and natural and ... referential then (r, a)-> r(cos a, i sin a) ... and rectangular form makes addition and subtraction easy, multiplication and powers tolerable, and root freaking impossible.  But polar notation makes addition hard, but multiplication, powers and root UTTERLY ***TRIVIAL***.  Don't shun it!  It *is* your friend and it *is* the magic and fundimental core of *all* complex analysis.  Seriously, once you learn about roots of unity... this is how you *have* to do everything.

Comment: This is great, I appreciate the advice! I'm taking complex analysis next year, so I should probably start getting comfortable with it sooner rather than later. Thanks a lot!